# How to add volume to Docker but exclude files

Tags: docker

I would like to mount everything inside my current directory, except 2 files.
log4j.properties and datanucleus.properties

myapp/config:/root/myapp/config

My directory structure is as follows

config

subdir1

subdir2

subdir3

log4j.properties

datanucleus.properties

I currently have to manually mount all the paths as following:

myapp/config/subdir1:/root/myapp/config/subdir1

myapp/config/subdir2:/root/myapp/config/subdir2

myapp/config/subdir3:/root/myapp/config/subdir3

Is there any option to mount everything in a directory and exclude few files

Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your folder structure currently is:

```
$ tree config/
config/
|-- datanucleus.properties
|-- log4j.properties
|-- subdir1
|   `-- subdir1 -> subdir1
|-- subdir2
|   `-- subdir2 -> subdir2
`-- subdir3
    `-- subdir3 -> subdir3
```

One workaround is to leverage the use of symlinks. Do this:

```
mkdir dockerconfig
cd dockerconfig
ln -s ../originalconfig/subdir1 subdir1
ln -s ../originalconfig/subdir2 subdir2
ln -s ../originalconfig/subdir3 subdir3
cd ..
```

Yes, these will be dangling for now, but inside the container they won't.

Now, make two volume mounts, like:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/config:/root/originalconfig -v $PWD/dockerconfig:/root/config centos:6.8 /bin/bash
```

And, then inside the container, you will have:

```
[root@9d803b889464 ~]# tree /root/
/root/
|-- anaconda-ks.cfg
|-- config
|   |-- subdir1 -> ../originalconfig/subdir1
|   |-- subdir2 -> ../originalconfig/subdir2
|   `-- subdir3 -> ../originalconfig/subdir3
|-- install.log
|-- install.log.syslog
|-- originalconfig
|   |-- datanucleus.properties
|   |-- log4j.properties
|   |-- subdir1
|   |   `-- subdir1 -> subdir1
|   |-- subdir2
|   |   `-- subdir2 -> subdir2
|   `-- subdir3
|       `-- subdir3 -> subdir3
|-- subdir1
`-- subdir3

8 directories, 10 files
```

And now your app can use `/root/config`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The problem is that when my container starts it will update some properties in datanuclueus.properties based on the environment variables set in dockercompose.yml file. If I mount config folder, I am getting exception that datanuclues.properties file not found

Comment: You can keep a copy of the `datanuclues.properties` file inside the dockerconfig folder.

Comment: Our application is build on one open source platform and our image  extends that image. datanuclues.properties is generated in config directory by that image and our configurations are generated as subfolders inside config directory

Comment: Is there any disadvantage if I mount paths like this?                    myapp/config/subdir1:/root/myapp/config/subdir1
myapp/config/subdir2:/root/myapp/config/subdir2
myapp/config/subdir3:/root/myapp/config/subdir3